# From where does Visual Studio (2017 or 2015) enumerate the installed SDKs?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio does not properly show all installed windows SDKs, failing to reflect what is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10. My question for this forum is straight forward - does anyone know where Visual Studio looks to enumerate all the installed SDK versions and their install location? Is there a props file or registry entry somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0
```

The key is InstallationFolder.

I discovered this by reading

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.props
```

The underlying issue I was seeing was that Visual Studio showed no Windows 10 dev kits as available, in spite of having two installed. I was able to fix the issue by taking the wow64 node from another machine that worked. It looked like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0]
"InstallationFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\"
"ProductName"="Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 10.0.15063"
"ProductVersion"="10.0.15063"
```

Comment: Well, that it digs it out of the registry is no great secret.  What is actually wrong with the keys?

Comment: In my case, there was no entry in the wow6432 node and the InstallationFolder was not set in the 64-bit node. I checked another PC that worked and found it only had the wow64 one, so after exporting that and importing it on the broken PC it fixed the issue for me. I think the installer for an SDK failed as this happened after I tried to install the creators update SDK.

Comment: Just put that in your answer, given that it actually answers the question.

Comment: Technically my question was where does it look to enumerate the SDKs, which is the registry key, but I will expand the answer for completeness :)